# Proximity sensor access on click of a button

Tags: android, proximity

I am new to android and I am trying to implement the count of  proximity sensor obstruction [ie number of times proximity sensor is blocked], on click of a button. I am not sure where I have made the mistake since i went through most of the materials available. Kindly point out the same if I am doing any 
mistake.

```
package com.fit.compaq.fitkit;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
 import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class pushup extends AppCompatActivity
{
int count;

Sensor proximity;
SensorManager sm;
TextView text;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pushup);

    ToggleButton pushupbutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbutton_pushup);


    pushupbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v)

                                        {
                                            sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
                                            proximity = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
                                            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_pushup_counter);



                                            final SensorEventListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

                                                 @Override
                                                public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sensor changed:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                                    text.setText(+event.values[0] + "");

                                                    if (event.values[0] < event.sensor.getMaximumRange()) {
                                                        count++;
                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Count = " + count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

                                                }

                                                protected void onResume() {

                                                    sm.registerListener(this, proximity,
                                                            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

                                                }


                                                protected void onPause() {


                                                    sm.unregisterListener(this);
                                                }
                                            };
                                        }
                                    }
    );
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_pushup, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Add some code so we can help you. So far we have no idea where the error even is.

Comment: I am not getting any errors as such , just not getting any sensor values after click of the button which invokes proximity sensor.